# Is it okay to use object pointer to overload assignment operator?

Tags: c++, overloading, variable-assignment

Suppose we want to implement a Complex Number class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{  
public:
    double real;
    double imag;

    Complex();
    Complex(double _r, double _i)
        :real(_r),imag(_i){}
    const Complex* operator = (const Complex*);
};
```

Normally to overload assignment operator we would pass a const reference as parameter, but why can't we pass a pointer instead, like this?

```
const Complex* Complex::operator = (const Complex* cp){
    real = cp->real;
    imag = cp->imag;
    return this;
}

int main(){

    Complex c1(1,2), c2(3,4), c3(5,6);
    Complex *pc = &c3;

    c1 = c2 = pc;
    cout<<"c1 = "<<c1.real<<"+"<<c1.imag<<'i'<<endl;
    cout<<"c2 = "<<c2.real<<"+"<<c2.imag<<'i'<<endl;
    cout<<"c3 = "<<c2.real<<"+"<<c2.imag<<'i'<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs and give the answer just as I expected: all three complex numbers yield `5+6i`.

I know this approach is rather unorthodox, but it seems to work as well. I'm wondering why our teacher strongly recommended us to use reference for assignment? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Your `Complex` class doesn't need any assignment operator, the compiler-generated one does what it's supposed to.

Comment: `*this` is not a `Complex*`.

Comment: "why can't we" - I have a more important question. Why **would** you? Your teacher recommends references because they were added to C++ for various good reasons, including implementing copy/assignment constructors, operator overloading, etc. Do you think you know better? I have nothing against pointers and use them often, but I _do_ dislike when they're used in inappropriate situations, like here.

Comment: Your code works but it is poor style. Any C++ programmer reading your code would wonder what the heck was going on, and then when they eventually figured out what you did, they'd have a few choice words. If you ever want to collaborate on C++ projects you would not have code like this accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that if you wish. But it's not a good idea.

Usually you'd imagine that an assign takes an object of the same type:

```
/*typeA*/ A = /*typeA*/ B;
```

a more real problem is that pointers are ints. You would assume that the code:

```
  Complex c = 5;
```

sets a complex `{5, 0}`, instead it will segfault (some compilers will warn you that int->complex* conversion was probably not intended, but sooner or later it, one cast<> or another, it will happen)